# Combing several subqueries in IF statement

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, for-loop

Current directory contains new logs that keep coming.
 /tmp/logstash/ dir contains logs to which I will be comparing new ones

Conditions:
  If the new log has the same name and the size that already exists in /tmp/logstash, I should get 'identical file already exists' msg.
 Otherwise the script will move the new log to /tmp/logstash/.

Note, that if name is same but size is different, the script should still move new file to tmp/logstash/

My script is as follows and it's not working properly with with combining 'then && if', can you please help to fix it?

```
for file in *.log; do
    new_filesize=$(du -b "$file" | cut -f 1)
    if [[ -e /tmp/logstash/"$file" ]]
    then
        old_filesize=$(du -b /tmp/logstash/"$file" | cut -f 1) &&
            if [[ "$new_filesize"="$old_filesize" ]]; then
                echo "The file already exists"
            fi
    else mv $file /tmp/logstash
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Test for Existence, if so Test Filesize, otherwise Copy

Per your request in the comments. The following tests whether `old_file` exists. If it does, it then checks whether the sizes between `new_file` and `old_file` differ. If they differ, then it moves `new_file` to `/tmp/logstash/` replacing `old_file`. If `old_file` exists and the files sizes are equal, then it will `echo "The file already exists"`. In the event `old_file` doesn't exist, then is simply copies `new_file` to `/tmp/logstash/`.

```
for file in *.log; do
    if [ -e /tmp/logstash/"$file" ]; then
        if [ $(stat %s "$file") -ne $(stat %s /tmp/logstash/"$file") ]
            mv -f "$file" /tmp/logstash
        else
            echo "The file already exists"
        fi
    else
        cp "$file" /tmp/logstash/"$file"
    fi
done
```

**Note:** Remember **quote your variables**.

---

### With Variables `new_filesize` and `old_filesize`

```
for file in *.log; do
    new_filesize=$(stat %s "$file")
    if [ -e /tmp/logstash/"$file" ]; then
        old_filesize=$(stat %s /tmp/logstash/"$file")
        if [ $new_filesize -ne $old_filesize ]
            mv -f "$file" /tmp/logstash
        else
            echo "The file already exists"
        fi
    else
        cp "$file" /tmp/logstash/"$file"
    fi
done
```

**Note:** `mv -f` was added to all cases where `old_file` exists to prevent move failure due to existing file.

Comment: Why `-gt` instead of `-ne`?

Comment: Good point. I was just thinking `newer`, but `-ne` works just as well.

Comment: @Barmar I guess he didn't tell us where they were coming from, so they could be older. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: Now I see that you're comparing the mod time. I thought it was the size, which is more likely to fluctuate in different directions.

Comment: Your point is still valid. If they get there from an `rsync -a` or `cp -a` from an older source somewhere else, `-ne` will catch it where `-gt` won't.

Comment: Why are you comparing modtime at all? He wants to compare size.

Comment: Again, just a less elegant way to skin the cat. I was looking at time (`newer`) when he asked for size. Double-good catch.. Fixing.

Comment: This is fine, but what if $(stat %s /tmp/logstash/"$file") says the file is not found?

Comment: Say, I need to make sure that if the file exists, it will then create a variable old_filesize to check the size, otherwise it should just copy the new file to the logs directory.

Comment: `$(stat %s "$file")` is the **file size** in bytes. I'll add variables instead of just the the `stat` call.

Comment: Glad I could help. The unix shell (and all of its variants, Bash, Zsh, Ksh, etc..) are pretty incredible environments. You can do just about anything that involves management of a unix/Linux system through scripting.

Answer (score 2):

You need spaces around the `=` in the conditional expression:

```
if [[ $new_filesize = $old_filesize ]]; then
```

Without the spaces, you're just testing whether the concatenated string `"$new_filesize"="$old_filesize"` is non-empty.